# YUI datatable column count

Tags: yui, yui-datatable

How do I get column count of a YUI datatable?

```
            var columns = dataTable.columns;
            var length = columns.length;
```

doesn't work.

I am using YUI2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In YUI2:

http://yui.github.io/yui2/docs/yui_2.9.0_full/docs/YAHOO.widget.DataTable.html

```
getColumnSet
YAHOO.widget.ColumnSet getColumnSet ( )
Returns the DataTable instance's ColumnSet instance.

 Returns: YAHOO.widget.ColumnSet
 ColumnSet instance.
```

like so:

```
var columnDefinitions = dataTable.getColumnSet().getDefinitions();
var length = columnDefinitions.length;
```

Answer (score 3):

The Columns of a DataTable instance are held as an Attribute, not a property, so you'd need to use the following code:

```
dataTable.get("columns").length;
```

Comment: I think it is for YUI3.